Tensile Strength and Young's modulus of 2D vs 3D Materials
I was wondering as to why graphene has not taken over the world. The obvious answer was that we cannot produce large sheets of it and it is expensive. Anyways, the article did mention something else, about graphene being the strongest compound:

Graphene is the thinnest compound known to man at one atom thick, the lightest material known (with 1 square meter weighing around 0.77 milligrams), the strongest compound discovered (between 100-300 times stronger than steel with a tensile strength of 130 GPa and a Young's modulus of 1 TPa - 150,000,000 psi)

This does seem reasonable(it was released in 2021), however I wanted to know whether there are other 2D materials(not hypothetical) or 3D materials since then that are stronger than graphene in terms of tensile strength and Young's modulus. Furthermore, are 2D material(in general) stronger than 3D materials in terms of tensile strength and Young's Modulus. Can we intuitively think of it that way(exceptions can be there)? And if so, why are 2D materials stronger in general?

According to the Engineering Toolbox, graphene and carbon nanotube have the same value for their Young's Modulus while that of diamond is $1.22 \times$!

Graphene is not a compound and even calling it a material is rather a misnomer. Only thing that is made of graphene molecules is graphite and hardly has some magical durability.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21840/why-is-graphene-so-strong

However, does current technology allow to generate a continuous fiber of graphene (or fibers long enough to yield threads and yarns, like for cotton), can these sheets easily bend to roll-up on a coil (like a wire of Cu) without loosing mechanical integrity and is this still affordable (from economic and ecologic perspective)?
